# Post about substitution for eggs (if eggs aren't available) is on hold and possibly going to be closed.

Tags: discussion, questions

Can my post be reopened if it closed already? If not, can you lift the hold?

This definitely makes someone's life much easier if eggs aren't available or not enough money to buy a dozen of eggs.

It was said that my post was *off-topic* and it is not a hack, but at the same time he also noted that "*Technically it is* a hack.

Original post is [here](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/9438/alternative-to-using-an-egg)

Answer (score 6):

The point I raised [in my comment](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/9438/alternative-to-using-an-egg#comment13249_9438) is that simple "ingredient substitutions" are such a common and well-documented part of cooking, something you can simply look up in any number of recipe books or references didn't feel like a hack to me. Technically it is, I guess. But turn to the chapter on ingredient substitutions — I'll leave it up the the community to decide if something you can look up in any reference book feels like a "hack" in the context of this site.

Answer (score -1):

We do have requests for [substite-tool](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/substite-tool) (see [tag info](//lifehacks.stackexchange.com/tags/substitute-tool/info)), but I for one, has not seen request for replacing specific ingredients of a cooking recipes before. However this specific request felt off-topic, and as commented sounded more appropriate for the [Seasoned Advice SE](//cooking.stackexchange.com/) site.

But the line between what is a lifehack, a common knowledge solution, or a request better answered on a different site, could be a little blurry. And sometimes it can even be on-topic for several sites, which makes it even harder.

So your question is currenlty on-hold as off-topic, and I don't see any good reasons to re-open it. And normally the procedure to reopen would be for you to make (a substantial) edit to your post, and vote for *reopen* in a link below the answer.